# Is there a way that a trigger on parent table will also listen to all child tables in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a parent table and more than 800 child tables for each of the clients. I want to create the same trigger for each of them. Is there a way that I can directly create it for the parent table and each child table will listen to it?

I can write a script to create the same for each client table but I am specifically looking for any direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **[inherit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html)** then you create the trigger for the main table and the changes occurs on the child table.

This is an example for insert trigger, you can see I only insert on the main table `avl` same go for updates or deletes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avl_db.avl_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-02 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170601 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-02 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-03 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170602 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-03 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-04 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170603 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-04 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-05 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170604 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-05 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-06 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170605 VALUES (NEW.*);
....
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date out of range.';
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL; -- avoid insert in the main table
```

More details on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954294/how-avoid-the-scan-in-the-main-table) I just made