# How avoid the scan in the main table

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-9.4

I have a table partitioned using inherit in multiple tables for days.

[image]

There is one insert trigger to insert the data to the proper table, so in theory the avl table shouldnt have any data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avl_db.avl_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-02 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170601 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-02 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-03 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170602 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-03 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-04 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170603 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-04 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-05 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170604 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSEIF ( NEW.event_time >= '2017-06-05 00:00:00' AND NEW.event_time < '2017-06-06 00:00:00' ) THEN 
        INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_20170605 VALUES (NEW.*);
....
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date out of range.';
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
```

Every table has a check constraint and index so only check the table with the right date

```
CONSTRAINT avl_20170605_event_time_check 
CHECK (event_time >= '2017-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone 
   AND event_time <  '2017-06-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)

CREATE INDEX avl_20170605__event_time_idx
  ON avl_db.avl_20170605
  USING btree
  (event_time);
```

The thing is when do select using the `event_time` to filter still do some operation over the main `avl` table.

```
explain analyze
    SELECT *
    FROM avl_db.avl
    WHERE event_time between '2017-06-05 09:40:44'::timestamp without time zone - '6 minute'::interval
                         AND '2017-06-05 09:40:44'::timestamp without time zone - '1 minute'::interval
```

You can see use the index from `avl_20170605__event_time_idx` and ignore the rest of the tables, but also try to do a Seq Scan on `avl`.

```
Append  (cost=0.00..720.98 rows=7724 width=16) (actual time=0.044..5.523 rows=7851 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on avl  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((event_time >= '2017-06-05 09:34:44'::timestamp without time zone) AND (event_time <= '2017-06-05 09:39:44'::timestamp without time zone))
  ->  Index Scan using avl_20170605__event_time_idx on avl_20170605  (cost=0.42..720.98 rows=7723 width=16) (actual time=0.042..5.110 rows=7851 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((event_time >= '2017-06-05 09:34:44'::timestamp without time zone) AND (event_time <= '2017-06-05 09:39:44'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 3.050 ms
Execution time: 5.737 ms
```

I'm wondering if there is a way optimizer stop trying to scan and append the table `avl`.

Comment: For just a single row, doing a `Seq Scan` is the only efficient way.

Comment: Also, show us your create trigger -- is it a before or after?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see the `row=1`. But that doesn't make any sense, there shouldn't be any rows there. Is there a way I can see what row is there? And my question is more like when I add the `CHECK` constraint the optimizer only check one table. So maybe I can set so ignore the main table.

Comment: `row=1` is an _estimate_. The actual number of rows for that table is indeed `0` (see the `(actual ... rows=0` part). With that row estimate and that number of real rows, a `Seq Scan` **is** the best choice the optimizer can take. An execution plan is not something static. If the number of rows and the distribution of values changes the optimizer will pick a different (better) plan to deal with more rows. Currently everything is fine, nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok then, btw thanks for the explanation now I understand a litle more how read the plan.  The append rows are the same from the index scan.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal and as it should be.

Every scan on a partitioned table will also scan the (usually empty) parent table, since it doesn't (and cannot) have a `CHECK` constraint like the child tables have.

You can see that this scan doesn't contribute any time to the overall query duration.